# Are the ombudsman's decisions of German universities legally binding?

Tags: plagiarism, germany, legal-issues, research-misconduct, personal-misconduct

I was accused of academic and administrative misconduct by one of my students several months ago in Germany. Finally, it was proved that I was innocent and there was no wrong doing on my side.

Now, this student is sending around e-mails (under a fake name, but I know who is the sender) and he is defaming me that I'm a fraudster and a thief. Our university, as a whole, has a plan to initiate a lawsuit against this person. As a person who is defamed, I also want to take this student to court. My questions is: Can I prove my innocence to the court by invoking the ombudsman's results? Or, will court ask for a new investigation by involving other universities?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Law.SE. Procedural questions like this could use that expertise.

Comment: I'd be surprised if any such administrative/disciplinary process anywhere had the force of law in the sense you mean. It might carry some weight, though and the same evidence might weigh in your favor in a court. (Caveat: not a German academic.)

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert on German law, so this isn't a direct answer to your question. But I think it's worth addressing some of the general issues raised by your question.

First, it is likely that the Ombudsman decisions are significantly limited in the extent to which they are binding. In Australia, for example, the role of the [Commonwealth Ombudsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ombudsmen_in_Australia) is that of a "[merits reviewer](https://www.ag.gov.au/legal-system/administrative-law/administrative-review-council-publications/what-decisions-should-be-subject-merit-review-1999)" rather than a judicial decision maker; the same applies to decisions made by other lower-level administrative tribunals such as the [Information Commissioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Information_Commissioner). Even decisions of the (now abolished) [Australian Administrative Appeals Tribunal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Appeals_Tribunal) (AAT) were binding only on Australian Government Departments and not on anyone else. My expectation would be that the Ombudsman decision to which you refer would be, at best, binding on the university. If, for example, the university had suspended your employment, the Ombudsman might be able to make a binding review decision that required the university to reinstate you, but the decision would not affect any other person or institution.

Another thing to consider is that the standard of evidence usually required in Ombudsman reviews is very different from that required in other judicial processes ... which brings me to the issue of defamation. You talk of wanting to sue the student for defamation and of your certainty that he (or she) is behind the apparently disparaging emails. However, unless you were able to *prove* that the origin of the emails is indeed the student, as you say, it is unlikely that you would even be able to initiate, let alone prosecute, a claim for defamation. Nor, in a [common-law style jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law) at least, would be able to secure an injunction against the student because you would lack evidence that he was the perpetrator. The potential obstacles in the path of pursing legal redress seem very high indeed.

Third, consider the likely unprofitable nature of pursuing legal avenues. You are probably feeling particularly emotionally "raw" having endured both the previous allegations and the process to clear your name. Thoughts of revenge and redress are likely to be high in your mind. But is it really worth pursuing further?

I know of a number of academics whose (successful) pursuit of redress for defamation actually cost far more, in terms of emotional energy, life and money, than any award that they were given by the courts. Their professional careers suffered significantly, not because of the background noise of the defaming emails, but because their focus was to much on their own feelings of hurt and too little on the real world of their academic reputation and research.

If your reputation among your friends and colleagues is reasonably intact, then my suggestion would be to get on with your life, to further cultivate your professional relationships, and to ignore the background behavior of the alleged perpetrator. As the old saying goes, the best revenge is to live well.